# Filtering ICollectionView binded to ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I want to make an WPF app for browsing recipes for dishes. Having trouble with filtering data.

I'm using ItemsControl to make my data look like "tiles" in the window. Now i want to filter it with TextBox, but I cant figure what is wrong.

Here is my XAML binding:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="573">
```

Textbox:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="Szukaj" Text="{Binding Szukane, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27.667" Margin="18.667,145,0,0" IsEnabled="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197.333" FontSize="14" />
```

C# code with filtering

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Przepis> lista {get; set; }

public ICollectionView ItemsView
{
    get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lista); }
}

public Page1(ObservableCollection<Przepis> l)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lista = l;

    ItemsView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => Filter(o as Przepis));
    this.DataContext = ItemsView;
}

private bool Filter(Przepis p)
{
    return Szukane == null
        || p.NazwaPrzepisu.IndexOf(Szukane, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
        || p.RodzajDiety.IndexOf(Szukane, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
        || p.RodzajPosilku.IndexOf(Szukane, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1;
}

private string szukane;

public string Szukane
{
    get { return szukane; }
    set
    {
        szukane = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Szukane");
        ItemsView.Refresh();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this.DataContext = ItemsView;` - with such DataContext binding `Text="{Binding Szukane}"` cannot possibly work, bacause Szukane is not a property of ItemsView. you need to change binding source:

`Text="{Binding Szukane, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page} UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Alternatively create a view model, with contains both ItemsView and Szukane properties, and use it for DataContext.

I also recommend to add a delay for Text binding to reduce amount of filtering while typing:

`Text="{Binding Szukane, Delay=250, RelativeSource=...}`