# Fix Search filter C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to do a search filter on my program. I've already seen this post to understand how to start ([Filtering ICollectionView binded to ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209535/filtering-icollectionview-binded-to-itemscontrol)), but I have some errors that I can't fix.

```
public class SchedulingPageVm : PageViewModel
{
   private readonly NcManager _ncManager;
   private readonly Scheduler _scheduler;
   private String _ncResearch;
   public ICollection<Nc> Ncs => _ncManager.Ncs;

   public string _NcResearch
   {
       get { return _ncResearch; }
       set
       {
           _ncResearch = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("NcList");
       }
   }

   private RelayCommand _search;
   public RelayCommand Search => _search ??= new RelayCommand(_Search);

   public SchedulingPageVm(ICollection<JobDocument> ElencoNc)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       ElencoNc = (ICollection<JobDocument>)_ncManager.Ncs;

       NcView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(object => _Search(object as _ncResearch));
       this.DataContext = _ncManager.Ncs;
   }

   private bool _Search(JobDocument elencoNc)
   {
       return _ncResearch == null
           || elencoNc.Code.IndexOf(_ncResearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
           || elencoNc.FileName.IndexOf(_ncResearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1
           || elencoNc.FilePath.IndexOf(_ncResearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1;
   }

   public CollectionView NcView
   {
       get { return (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_ncManager.Ncs); }
   }

   public ObservableCollection<Nc> DataContext { get; }
```

Errors:

1. `public RelayCommand Search => _search ??= new RelayCommand(_Search);`

   > Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'
2. `NcView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(object,_Search(object as _ncResearch));`

   > The type or namespace name '_ncReasearch' could not be found (you are missing a using directive or an assembly reference)*
   > *Error invalid expression term 'object'

Comment: `_ncResearch` is a variable, it can't be used as a type in `as` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'

The `RelayCommand` expects a method signature like this.

```
void _Search(object obj)
```

Your `_Search` method does not match. You can either introduce a lambda to cast the `object`:

```
public RelayCommand Search => _search ??= new RelayCommand(obj => _Search((JobDocument)obj));
```

Or you can change the signature of the `_Search` method and cast the object in it, but I guess you need this method to return a `bool` for the filter, so you cannot do this.

```
private bool _Search(object obj)
{
   var elencoNc = (JobDocument) obj;
   // ...other code.
}
```

However, the main question here is why you create a command for this in the first place. The command does not return anything and your `_Search` method is a predicate, so it does not change any state. The invocation of the command does not do anything except waste CPU time.

> The type or namespace name '_ncReasearch' could not be found (you are missing a using directive or an assembly reference) Error invalid expression term 'object'

You are creating the `Predicate<object>` wrong. A predicate of that type gets an `object` instance as parameter and returns a `bool` as result of its check. On the left side of the `as` operator needs to be an instance and on the right side the type to cast to, here `JobParameter`.

```
NcView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(obj => _Search(obj as JobDocument));
```

You could even cast the `obj` directly like `(JobDocument) obj` and assign the `Filter` directly.

```
NcView.Filter = obj => _Search((JobParameter) obj);
```

Read more on the `as` operator in the documentation: [as operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator)